# How to use an Anylogic Object (INode) as a Type when using Databases

Tags: excel, database, anylogic, inode

The Problem: I have database tables (imported excel) with **orders** and **locations**. The orders have a column called "destination" that is cross referenced (using "Foreign Key" to reference locations.location) to the location column **locations** table which is supposed to represent the actual INode. How do i specify this address say in a moveTo block?

1. I dont see an option where i can specify INode as the type in the Database table. I get a permission error if i choose Other as type and try to write INode.
2. How do i effect this cross reference in code or in the Actions line? Its already set up with a foreign key in the agent table/parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot represent AnyLogic objects like `INode` as database entries. Instead, you can store characteristics *about* the node and create nodes programmatically at the model start.

So store things like X/Y coordinates, etc.

Below is an example for GIS points to show you the approach. You need to do something similar for INodes (check the AnyLogic help for INode API to learn how to create them).

I store the location name as a string in the dbase:
[image]

On the model startup, I programmatically create `GISPoint` elements from the data (assumes I have a GIS map called `map`):

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(routes)
.list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
        GISPoint locationFrom = map.searchFirst(row.get( routes.location_from ));
        GISPoint locationTo = map.searchFirst(row.get( routes.location_to ));
        map.add(locationFrom);
        map.add(locationTo);
        GISRoute route = map.getRoute(locationFrom.getLatitude(), locationFrom.getLongitude(), 
             locationTo.getLatitude(), locationTo.getLongitude());
        route.setLineColor( spectrumColor(uniform_discr(1,10), 10) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Benjamin, I was hoping that i could just leave it in a spreadsheet and just update it there when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

### The idea: Parsing

I agree with Benjamin: You cannot directly save a reference to the Java object of an INode. If you still  want to use predefined INodes, you can  save the textual name of your node in the Excel/database and then parse ("convert") it to the reference of the INode with this name.

### How to do it

To prepare for this, it is easiest to manually put all INodes that you want to potentially retrieve into one Collection, for this example I name it `allMyINodes`:

[image: collection of all nodes]

Then one can use a parsing function, here is one proposal:
`INode getINodeByName(String nodeName)`:

```java
INode myNode;

myNode = allMyINodes.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(nodeName))
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);

return myNode;
```

[image: parsing function]

Here is an [example project](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/591012f1-666e-4f5d-9400-2410064402ca?mode=SETTINGS) in the Anylogic Cloud, you can run and download the source files there as well.

### Applying it to your scenario

In your application, this means that for example in a moveTo-block, you would write 
`getINodeByName(....here the code to get one node name from the db....)` for your destination of type INode.

As to your second question on how to retrieve the location based on a found order and a link by key, I think this is a separate question and only database/SQL related, maybe you open a separate post on this with an SQL tag.

Comment: Thanks Florian. And thanks for uploading the example. I have something similar using a function and case/switch statements. I have never used the filter/streams, and i have only a rudimentary understanding of lambda. So I will use this simple case to get more exposure to it.